# Conflicting 'p' styles

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

When calling an excerpt in Wordpress, is there a way to stop the excerpt carrying over it's own 'p' styling? Ending up with 2 conflicting styles.

This is my PHP code;

```
<h2 class="blog"><?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?></h2>
<p class="blog"><?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?></p>
</div>
```

This is how it appears in source code;

```
<div id="blog">
<h2 class="blog"><a href="http://kelvinwinscom.fatcow.com/kelvinwins/test-2/">Test 2</a>
</h2>
<p class="blog"><p>This is what an excerpt is. Interesting, isn&#8217;t it? <a href="http://kelvinwinscom.fatcow.com/kelvinwins/test-2/">Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></a></p>
</p>
</div>
```

See, there is now two 'p' styles - the 'blog' class which I've created but also the other one that the excerpt is carrying over.

Any help would be brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: I have put the code directly into the question -- please avoid linking to remote code as much as possible so StackOverflow can be a resource in itself and so that the question makes sense even if a remote website/resource no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the `<p class="blog">` from your php

```
<p class="blog">// REMOVE THE PROCEEDING <?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'offset' => 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?></p> //REMOVE THE </p>
```

and then style that `<p>` in your stylesheet as an [adjacent sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors):

```
h2.blog + p {//whatever your styles are}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your theme function

```
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```